# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sos'

Tags: python, python-3.x

hiii!!! I am following a course, called `Python Game Development™ : Build 11 Total Games`
and I've came across on an error, and I just started the course, I'm on video 26!
and, I have an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python games\base.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sos
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sos'
```

and Im confused, I don't know how to fix it, since the person didn't get this error.
if u could help me that'll be great & appreciated!! + this is my code :

```
import collection

import math

import sos

def path(filename):
    filepath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    dirpath = os.path.dirname
    fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
    return fullpath

def line(a,b,x,y):
    import turtle
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(a,b)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.goto(x,y)

class vector(collection.Sequence):
    PRECISION = 6
    __slots__ = ('_x','_y','_hash')

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self._hash = None
        self._x = round(x,self.PRECISION)

    @property
    #getter
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,value):
        if self._hash is not None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot set x after hashing')
        self._x = round(value,self.PRECISION)

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
    @y.setter
    def y(self,value):
        if self._hash is not None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot set x after hashing')
        self._x = round(value,self.PRECISION)
```

edit : someone helped me, and the only error now is the *import sos* !

it is not fully done since I'm trying to fix this error, so please help me out ! thank you :)

tried looking back at the course if I missed anything, I don't think I did.

Comment: Maybe *import collections* ?

Comment: thank you! the error is gone now, but I just found out the person made a typo and didn't fix it on screen.

Comment: There are **MANY** errors in that code. Suggest you communicate with the author. Even after correcting the imports, it won't work. The *path()* function will raise a TypeError exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `import os` instead of `import sos`

`dirpath = os.path.dirname()` ## do not forget the parentheses

value `y` in the constructor `__init__` is missing

the setter method for `y` sets the wrong attribute `x`.